# Illogical TypeMismatch in a for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code

```
Dim myDataRng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim col_array(3) As String

col_array(1) = "F"
col_array(2) = "G"
col_array(3) = "H"

Dim uB As Integer, lB As Integer
uB = UBound(col_array)
lB = LBound(col_array)

Dim col_str As String

For i = lB To uB
    col_str = CStr(col_array(i))
    Set myDataRng = Range(col_str & "1:" & col_str & Cells(Rows.Count, col_str).End(xlUp).Row)
Next I
```

When executing I receive the error message:
"Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

It affects the line of code:

```
Set myDataRng = Range(col_str & "1:" & col_str & Cells(Rows.Count, col_str).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Especially the part

```
Cells(Rows.Count, col_str)
```

Outside the loop, the affected line of code works.
What is the reason for the error message? The data type is definitely correct.

Comment: What is the value of `col_str` before the error? Usually the array starts from 0 and `col_array(3)` would mean 4 elements, starting from 0 to 4. You are filling the value in the array by 1st index which should have been 0. Is the value of `col_str_` blank for the 0th element causing the error?

Comment: Simple fix: `Dim col_array(1 To 3) As String`

Comment: ... i.e. the first element of the array is `col_array(0)` which is `""` and is 'transferred' to `col_str`, so `Cells(Rows.Count, col_str)` or `Cells(Rows.Count, "")` is invalid.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks. Indeed the value of i starts with 0 instead of 1. I fixed the problem with Dim col_array(1 To 3) As String.

Answer (score 3):

As already written in the comments: Your problem is that you declare your array without specifying the lower, only the upper bound (3).

```
Dim col_array(1 to 3) As String  ' declares 3 elements, from 1 to 3
Dim col_array(0 to 3) As String  ' declares 4 elements, from 0 to 3
Dim col_array(3) As String       ' probably declares 4 elements
```

Why do I write "probably"? When you omit the lower bound, VBA uses 0 as default. Except, if you use `Option Base 1`, that changes the default for the lower bound to 1 in that module (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement)

My advice is to always specify the lower bound for any static array.

You could use the following alternative to create your array. That saves you from counting the number of elements in advance:

```
Dim col_array()
col_array = Array("F", "G", "H")
```

You should btw split complex statements into pieces - this makes it much easier to read and to debug:

```
Dim lastRow As Long, rangeAdr As String
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, col_str).End(xlUp)
rangeAdr = col_str & "1:" & col_str & lastRow
Set myDataRng = Range(rangeAdr)
```

Instead of dealing with Range-addresses as String, you could also define the range using the first and last cell which makes it more readable:

```
Set myDataRng = Range(Cells(1, col_str), Cells(lastRow, col_str))
```

And, of course, you should always qualify your Ranges and Cells so that you don't rely on the active sheet.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)    ' <-- Change to whatever you need
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col_str).End(xlUp)
    Set myDataRng = .Range(.Cells(1, col_str), .Cells(lastRow, col_str))
End With
```